# Gsutil ls output in a text file

Tags: list, google-workspace, gsutil

I would like to check if there is any option that I can extract a gsutil ls command output into a text file.

I am trying to get a list of files that are in a bucket on GCP.

Is this possible to do?

command: gsutil ls gs://mybucket

Thanks in advance
Manuel

I've tried using gsutil ls gs://mybucket > output.txt but seems it is not possible.

Comment: What is going wrong with gsutil ls gs://mybucket > output.txt?  I just tried that and it works.

Comment: i've tried again and it worked for me as well. The question is where to find the output.txt file?

Comment: It would be in the local directory where you are running the command, but if you specified the full path you can place it where you wanted: "gsutil ls gs://mybucket > /full/path/to/output.txt

Comment: Thanks Travis I've managed to find the file when opening the code editor in the GCP itself.